# No me detecta los valores de mi SPAN a la hora de guardarlo en mi base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, html, base-de-datos

Este es mi HTML. Lo que quiero es que mi SPAN se guarde en una base de datos, pero a la hora de darle al boton de guardar los valores se me registran como 0.
He visto que la solucion podria ser poniendo un input, pero no se como aplicarlo al siguiente codigo

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/juego.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/js.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <h1 align="center" >Juego</h1>
</header>
<main>

<div>
<form class="guardar-form" action="guardar.php" method="POST">
  <section class="uno" >
    <h2 align="center" id="estadísticas-e">Estadísticas</h2>
      <span align="center" class="vida" id="vida-e"> Vida</span>
      <span align="center" class="vida" id="vida-e"> Vida</span>
        <span id="vidatotal" type="text" name="vidaB" placeholder="vidaB">100</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="vidaB" value="100">
      <span align="center" class="energia" id="energia-e"> Energia</span>
        <span id="dormido" type="number" name="energiaB" placeholder="energiaB">100</span>
      <span align="center" class="comida" id="comida-e"> Comida</span>
       <span align="center" id="hambre" type="number" name="comidaB" placeholder="comidaB">100</span>
        <button class="boton-guardar">Guardar</button>
  </section>
</div>

</form>
  <section class="cuatro">
    <h2 class="accion" align="center" >Acciones</h2>
    <article>
    <button onclick="dormir()" class="botonexplorar" >Dormir</button>
    </article>
    <article>
    <button onclick="cazar()" class="botonexplorar" >Cazar</button>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi js, el cual me funciona correctamente y hace lo que yo quiero

```
var a = 100;
var c = 100;
var h = 100;
var s = 100;



function dormir() {
  if (a > 99){
    alert("Te pasas")
  }
  else{
    a = a + 20;
    c = c + 5;
    document.getElementById("dormido").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("vidatotal").innerHTML = c;
    document.getElementById("vidatotal").innerHTML = c;
  }

}

function cazar() {

if(c < 1){
  alert("Has muerto")
}

  else{
    c = c - 20;
    a = a - 20;
    h = h - 5;
    s = s - 5;
    document.getElementById("vidatotal").innerHTML = c;
    document.getElementById("dormido").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("hambre").innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById("sed").innerHTML = s;
  }

}
```

Y este es mi PHP, el problema en el PHP es que solo me guarda los valores como 0 en la base de datos

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <?php
               include 'db_connect.php';
         $conn = open_con();

            if (!$conn) {
               die("Error a la connexió " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

        $vidaB = utf8_decode($_POST['vidaB']);
        $energiaB = utf8_decode($_POST['energiaB']);
        $comidaB = utf8_decode($_POST['comidaB']);
        $sedB = utf8_decode($_POST['sedB']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO guardar (vidaB,energiaB,comidaB,sedB)
            VALUES ('".$vidaB."','".$energiaB."','".$comidaB."', '".$sedB."')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Guardado exitosamente";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

            close_con($conn);
        ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Esto es principalmente para un juego que estoy creando a base del uso de HTML y JS

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente recoges los valores de los span y los pasas a la BD? Yo sólo veo que seteas valores con `innerHTML`, pero nunca veo que recoges el texto de los span... Otra cosa, tienes ids repetidos en algunos elementos, eso está  prohibido en HTML, porque precisamente si recuperas un elemento por su id podría estar seleccionando el primero que encuentre con ese id, o el último, o el del medio... según le dé la gana al DOM. Cada ID, como su nombre indica, debe ser único e irrepetible.

Comment: hola podes agregar un input ya con el valor asignado `<input type="text" name="" value="VALOR">`

Comment: @Daniel Ya lo habia tenido en cuenta, pero como tengo variables que se ejecutan al pulsar los botones el valor del inputo no cambia

Comment: @A.Cedano recogo los valores con `<button class="boton-guardar">Guardar</button>` que esta al final del primer div, y gracias por avisarme de que tengo IDs repetidos

Comment: No veo ninguna relación entre ese botón y el código JS de la pregunta. Por favor explica el contexto y pon el código que falte. El código actual no recoge en ningún lado lo que hay en los span.

Comment: @ShiroMB en ese caso intenta con `textarea`  `<textarea id="dormido" type="number" name="energiaB" placeholder="energiaB">100</textarea>`